# Android app_process segmentation fault trying to run own app

Tags: android, adb, dalvik

I am trying to run a java app/script from adb shell on an unrooted device without installing it as a package first. I tried to use app_process the same way as e.g. `am` is run - however I get a segmentation fault. I am wondering if this is possible at all considering security.

This is the code:

```
public class example {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello world");
        }
}
```

This works fine in Windows:

```
$ javac example.java
$ java example
Hello world
$ java -jar example.jar
Hello world
```

I created an example.jar file with a manifest and the class inside (I tried with and without the class as `am` does not use an executable jar) and uploaded both to `/sdcard/`. Now in the shell (via adb) I do the following, which just produces Segmentation Fault on the console:

```
base=/system && export CLASSPATH=/sdcard/example.jar && app_process $base/bin example
```

Here is what logcat says:

```
D/AndroidRuntime(14289): >>>>>> AndroidRuntime START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit <<<<<<
D/AndroidRuntime(14289): CheckJNI is OFF
D/AndroidRuntime(14289): setted country_code = UK
D/AndroidRuntime(14289): setted countryiso_code = GB
D/AndroidRuntime(14289): setted sales_code = TMU
D/AndroidRuntime(14289): readGMSProperty: start
D/AndroidRuntime(14289): readGMSProperty: already setted!!
D/AndroidRuntime(14289): readGMSProperty: end
D/AndroidRuntime(14289): addProductProperty: start
D/dalvikvm(14289): Trying to load lib libjavacore.so 0x0
D/dalvikvm(14289): Added shared lib libjavacore.so 0x0
D/dalvikvm(14289): Trying to load lib libnativehelper.so 0x0
D/dalvikvm(14289): Added shared lib libnativehelper.so 0x0
I/dalvikvm(14289): Zip is good, but no classes.dex inside, and no valid .odex file in the same directory
E/appproc (14289): ERROR: could not find class 'example'
E/JNIHelp (14289): Native registration unable to find class 'android/debug/JNITest', aborting
F/libc    (14289): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0xdeadbaad (code=1), thread 14289 (app_process)
I/DEBUG   ( 1835): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
I/DEBUG   ( 1835): Build fingerprint: 'samsung/GT-I9100/GT-I9100:4.1.2/JZO54K/I9100XWLSY:user/release-keys'
I/DEBUG   ( 1835): pid: 14289, tid: 14289, name: app_process  >>> app_process <<<
I/DEBUG   ( 1835): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr deadbaad
I/DEBUG   ( 1835):     r0 00000027  r1 deadbaad  r2 40141b0c  r3 00000000
I/DEBUG   ( 1835):     r4 00000000  r5 bec3690c  r6 402a8ea8  r7 00000002
I/DEBUG   ( 1835):     r8 402b1828  r9 400ddfc1  sl 400ddf94  fp 400ddfca
I/DEBUG   ( 1835):     ip 40181fe0  sp bec36908  lr 40113c65  pc 401102fe  cpsr 60000030
I/DEBUG   ( 1835):     d0  0000000000000004  d1  0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   ( 1835):     d2  0000000000000000  d3  0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   ( 1835):     d4  0000000000000000  d5  0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   ( 1835):     d6  0000000000000000  d7  83cc7a9b00000000
I/DEBUG   ( 1835):     d8  0000000000000000  d9  0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   ( 1835):     d10 0000000000000000  d11 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   ( 1835):     d12 0000000000000000  d13 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   ( 1835):     d14 0000000000000000  d15 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   ( 1835):     d16 0000000000000017  d17 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   ( 1835):     d18 4172e2b5a0000000  d19 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   ( 1835):     d20 0000000000000000  d21 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   ( 1835):     d22 0000000000000000  d23 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   ( 1835):     d24 0000000000000000  d25 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   ( 1835):     d26 0000000000000000  d27 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   ( 1835):     d28 0000000000000000  d29 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   ( 1835):     d30 0000000000000000  d31 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   ( 1835):     scr 60000010
I/DEBUG   ( 1835):
I/DEBUG   ( 1835): backtrace:
I/DEBUG   ( 1835):     #00  pc 000182fe  /system/lib/libc.so
I/DEBUG   ( 1835):     #01  pc 0000dc04  /system/lib/libc.so (abort+4)
I/DEBUG   ( 1835):     #02  pc 00000955  /system/lib/libnativehelper.so (jniRegisterNativeMethods+72)
I/DEBUG   ( 1835):     #03  pc 0004d4a7  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (android::AndroidRuntime::startReg(_JNIEnv*)+34)
I/DEBUG   ( 1835):     #04  pc 0004d5a5  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (android::AndroidRuntime::start(char const*, char const*)+200)
I/DEBUG   ( 1835):     #05  pc 00000dcf  /system/bin/app_process
I/DEBUG   ( 1835):
```

Is there any way to get this work? If yes what am I missing - I can see the ERROR in the log so the class is probably in the wrong place, by can I get it working from the .jar file, or from a location where I can put the class on an unrooted device?

My goal is to run a Java app/script (similar to how you can run am, pm, dumpsys) in the background using adb, doing some things, while the device runs other things as usual from the GUI, so I don't want to install it as a package / run an intent.

Comment: android can't run java bytecode.

Comment: http://milk.com/kodebase/dalvik-docs-mirror/docs/hello-world.html

Comment: Thank you, got it working now! To summarise, following up on the answer above:

- The code needs to be compiled and then using the 'dx' tool packaged as a Dalvik compatible .jar
- It can then be executed using 'dalvikvm -cp' or app_process. On newer Android versions Dalvik cache needs to be redirected to e.g. /sdcard.

Comment: I am just wondering whether this will also work on Lollipop (Android 5.0) since Dalvik has been replaced with ART? Anybody has experience with this?